# umbraco my site pages can navigate on any other page, how to stop this?

Tags: umbraco

i have website developed by [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/). It's working good except one thing.

Suppose i have the following pages under the parent node `content` :

login - register - about-us

if i type in the browser www.mysite/login/register it normally respond with the register page, which is not make sense

i navigate to every page under any other page(which is so weird) and i don't know why. Is there any changes i need to make in my IIS or web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a template called "register" you can apply that template to any page simply by putting "register" at the end of you url, as in:

```
www.mysite/login/register
```

If there is in fact no node that exists called "register" which lives under "login", then the above url effectively becomes:

```
www.mysite/login/?alttemplate=register
```

This is expected and useful behavior as described in [Why Umbraco Rocks - Alternate Templates](http://www.nibble.be/?p=42).

Comment: can i stop this behavior? i mean i need register to be displayed on it's specific url not under any each node

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no way to stop it, but the average user isn't going to go and append "register" or whatever to every page they're on, so you shouldn't worry about it. It's not like Google will crawl those urls either. If you're really bothered by it, I suppose you could rename your template aliases (for example from "register" to "registerTemplate").

Comment: i do changed the template name from "register" to another name and i gives me 404 .. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that these pages have no Alternative urls in the Umbraco backend? it should be named umbracoUrlAlias or something similar.

Comment: how can i check this please?

Comment: It depends on your developer's taste. 
clicking on each node in Umbraco Backend, in the right panel you can see numbers of tabs (also could be one!), check each tab and see whether for instance, for Node 'register', is there a link like 'www.mysite/login/register'?
Basically there should be one URL for each page listed in Properties Tab which is fine, but using umbracoUrlAlias or any other similar tools allows you to have multiple URLs for one Node.

Comment: have you used Umbraco before??